# What is the meaning of $(−\infty, \infty]$?

Tags: functions

What is the meaning of this mathematical notation for a function
$$f : \mathbb{R}^n \to (−\infty, \infty]$$
Especially I am wondering the left bracket and right square bracket?

Comment: The notation $(-\infty,\infty]$ denotes the set {t | $-\infty < t \leq \infty$}.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: Or else...? I find the question completely clear and readable.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I also understand what the OP wants, but I think the he should get used to MathJax.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: I think this site would be a lot more welcoming if we stopped biting the newcomers like that.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: I recognize that your wording has become less aggressive than it used to be, but the _principle_ of telling people they need to go and learn a new notation in order to participate in the site, when _what they want to say demonstrably does not require that_ is still off-putting and insular.

Comment: @HenningMakholm But isn't the spirit of the first answer reviews to tell the newcomers how things are supposed to be done around here?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: And "how things are supposed to be done here" is _not_ to tell newcomers that they need to learn a particular markup language in order to participate -- when they in fact _do not need that markup language_ for participating. And a newcomer's **first** encounter with the site should _certainly_ not be "go away and learn this irrelevant skill before we will deign to talk to you".

Comment: I will use the markup in my future questions/answers. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$(-\infty,\infty]$ is an interval of the [extended real line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line). It contains all the real numbers as well as the $\infty$ symbol, but *does not* contain the $-\infty$ symbol.

In other words, a values of the function $f$ will be either a real number or the special symbol $\infty$. What the properties of $\infty$ are here, other than counting as larger than every real number, must be understood from the context.